# Cannot drop to frame?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Is there a trick to get "Drop To Frame" to work with Android? The option is inactive for me.

[image]

Comment: Android 10 has supported this feature.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58749028/2782538

Answer (score 7):

I hope it is possible, but I don't think so.

Other nice functionalities like "All instances...", "Instance count" and watchpoints (stop debug on variable access/modification) are also unavailable.
I think it is because DalvikVM does not support this functions.

From eclipse documentation about [Drop to frame](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-droptoframe.htm):

> Note this command is only available if the current VM supports drop to frame and the selected stackframe is not the top frame or a frame in a native method.

Similar note can be found on page describing [All instances](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-allinstances.htm):

> This command is only available if the Java virtual machine you are currently using supports instance retrieval.

See my answer to my own similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697639/show-all-instances-missing-in-eclipse-debug-view).

Maybe there is an option to enable this functions on Dalvik.

**EDIT**

It may be a of little value, but if you use unit tests (using JUnit or Robolectric) than all those functions are available (since run on native JVM I think) and very helpful.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102484) i got the following comment

> The action only enables when the program you are debugging supports
>   the  operation. For example, the Java debugger supports the operation
>   when  debugging on a VM that supports it (1.4.x or higher), and there
>   are no native  methods on the call stack above the point you want to
>   drop to.