# Show "All Instances" missing in eclipse debug view

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, instances

few days ago, when I was debugging an Android project under eclipse I've found some great functionality: "All instances..." and "Instance count". I wanted to share my findings with rest of my colleagues, but none of them had this functionality in their eclipse install (we all use eclipse 3.7).

What's even more weird now I'm also missing this functionality.

As far as I can tell this functionality is build within eclipse from version 3.3 and available to projects using Java 1.6 and above as mentioned [here](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2011/05/eclipse-show-all-instances-of-selected.html) and [here](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli) (we're using 1.6).

See bottom of this [link](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli) to see what functionality I'm talking about. It even has it's own shortcut in options (ctrl+shift+n) so I think there must be a way to use it again.

I was looking for it while debugging and while the debugger was in "stopped" state.

Anyone can help me put eclipse in right view/perspective/state to see this functionality again?

**EDIT**

Here is the documentation entry from eclipse help page: [link](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-allinstances.htm)

Thanks for any suggestions,
kajman

Comment: I thought that it is better to leave question open so maybe someone would care to elaborate more,  than to accept a half-solution or some nasty workaround or "everyone says it can't be done". I even though about asking about this problem on stackoverflow-meta. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I came to following conclusion:

DalvikVM does not support "instance retrieval".

On eclipse help page mentioned in **EDIT** section it written:

> This command is only available if the Java virtual machine you are currently using supports instance retrieval.

Maybe there is an option to enable this option in DalvikVM, but I doubt it unfortunately.
Also when debugging on phone "Drop to frame" functionality is missing.