# Drop to Frame support in Eclipse Android Development Tools (ADT) debug mode

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, adt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot drop to frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611019/cannot-drop-to-frame)

In the Eclipse Android Development Tools (ADT) debug mode, the "Drop to Frame" is disabled.

Anyone managed to get it working in debug mode?

"Drop to Frame" is really useful in debugging code..

Comment: Related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611019/cannot-drop-to-frame

Comment: Can you make this as the answer?